# varnish cache based on url type

Tags: varnish-vcl

I am configuring varnish. I want if the requested url is "/balancer/50/s91.txt" then dont cache it. If the requested url is "/balancer/vod/website/test.flv" then cache it for 1 day.
I wrote

```
sub vcl_recv {    
 if (req.url ~ "vod") {
   return(lookup);
 }
  return(pass);
 }

sub vcl_fetch {  
  if (req.url ~ "vod") {
   # Cache for 1 day
   set beresp.ttl = 1d;
   return(deliver);
 }

 }
```

I am first time using it. Please help me how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like that :

```
sub vcl_recv {

  # If the requested url is "/balancer/50/s91.txt" then dont cache it.
  if (req.url ~ "^/balancer/50/s91.txt$") {
    return (pass);
  }

  # Cache everything else
  return (lookup);

}

sub vcl_fetch {
  # Default TTL.  
  set beresp.ttl = 10m;

  # /balancer/vod/website/test.flv : cache it for 1 day.
  if (req.url ~ "^/balancer/vod/website/test.flv$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1d;
  }
}
```

Here, I cache everything except /balancer/50/s91.txt. And I set a specific TTL of 24hours for /balancer/vod/website/test.flv.

Comment: How can I modify this to work with range request ? My varnish version is 3.0.5   ?